# Addition of two binary numbers using only logical operators AND, OR

Tags: c, binary, logical-operators, addition, digits

I am new to programming and I want to add up two binary numbers (e.g. '10' and '01') in C but I am not allowed to use:

- arithmetic operations +,-,*,/
- bitwise operators (<<,^...)
- iterations
- arrays

So I have to rely on if/else-conditions and the two logical operators &&, ||. I know how to build an XOR, but how can I reach the "higher" digit (digit '1' in '10') when I am not allowed to use division at all?
I have read about the library function div(), but wouldn't it technically violate the rules?

Comment: Ouch — my head just exploded.  This seems like a torture test, not something educational.

Comment: Show the exact text of the assignment. Prohibiting shift (`<<`) is unusual in an assignment to implement binary addition. What form are the so-called “binary numbers” in? `unsigned int`? A string of ASCII or other characters? Given two binary numbers ab and cd producing a sum efg, where each letter represents a binary digit, the result bit f mathematically depends on b and d as well as a and c, so there **must** be some cross-position operation, whether that is implemented via a shift or via some `if` operation on b and d that is used to select code affecting f.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the form/input of both numbers. I already thought about misunderstanding something. Input is digit by digit, not as a string. So binary '10' is actually respresented by '1' '0' (space between both digits). In this case I just can use logical operations to compare the digits on their own.

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented as binary addition when it is performed by hand, but it is a tedious and will be more difficult if negative numbers are included.

For example, when adding:

```
         +1
    eca 0001
    fdb 0011
        ----
        0100
```

something along these lines could be implemented (very simplified and incomplete logic)

```
if (a == 1 && b == 1)
{
  transferBit = 1;
  res_0 = 0;
}
if (c == 0 && d == 1 && transferBit == 1)
{  
   res_1 = 0;
}
if (e == 0 && f == 0 && transferBit == 1)
{
  transferBit = 0;
  res_2 = 1;
}
```

etc.